# Python: nested dictionary problem: trying to run a 'if' command to print out a string

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to do following 2 things for this nested dictionary:

1. If a bird is aggressive, print out a string advising us to 'cover our heads' using the 'actions' list in this print statement.
2. If a bird is endangered, print out a string advising us to 'back away', also using the actions list in this print statement.

Here's what I have so far. Any help is much appreciated!:

```
rarebirds = {
    'Gold-crested Toucan': {
        'Height (m)': 1.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 35,
        'Color': 'Gold',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': True},

'Pearlescent Kingfisher': {
        'Height (m)': 0.25,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Color': 'White',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Aggressive': False},

'Four-metre Hummingbird': {
        'Height (m)': 0.6,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Color': 'Blue',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': False},

'Giant Eagle': {
        'Height (m)': 1.5,
        'Weight (kg)': 52,
        'Color': 'Black and White',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': True},

'Ancient Vulture': {
        'Height (m)': 2.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 70,
        'Color': 'Brown',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Aggressive': False}
}

actions = ['Back Away', 'Cover our Heads', 'Take a Photograph']


for key, value in rarebirds.items():
    for value in value:
        if value == 'Aggressive' and True:
            print(key, ":", actions[1])
            return

for key, value in rarebirds.items():
     for value in value:
         if value == 'Endangered' and True:
         print(key, ":", actions[0])
         return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue identified:

1. indentation issue in second for loop.
2. `return` statement not required.
3. `if value == 'Aggressive' and True:` - This condition will be true for all the keys having `Aggressive` as one of its value, irrespective of whether it is `True` or `False`.

Since `rarebirds` is a `dict`, we don't want to iterate through the `value`. It can be written simply as,

```
for key, value in rarebirds.items():
    if value['Aggressive'] == True:
        print(key + ":" + actions[1])

for key, value in rarebirds.items():
    if value['Endangered'] == True:
        print(key + ":" + actions[0])
```

For the output,

```
Gold-crested Toucan:Cover our Heads
Giant Eagle:Cover our Heads
Gold-crested Toucan:Back Away
Four-metre Hummingbird:Back Away
Giant Eagle:Back Away
```

Comment: Avoid to explicitly check `== True`. If needed for extra clarity, use `is True`

Comment: I agree with you @Pynchia. We can even check like this, `if value['Aggressive']:`
@Newcoderpython :) Kindly consider this comment too

Answer (score 0):

Another way, is to build a sequence of names and actions as tuples.

Here the purpose is to show the use of generators, useful to avoid building extra data structures (note how even each tuple could be replaced by a generator, depending on its use).

For example, assuming you can take a picture of the neutral species only:

```
rarebirds = {
    'Gold-crested Toucan': {
        'Height (m)': 1.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 35,
        'Color': 'Gold',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': True},

'Pearlescent Kingfisher': {
        'Height (m)': 0.25,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Color': 'White',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Aggressive': False},

'Four-metre Hummingbird': {
        'Height (m)': 0.6,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Color': 'Blue',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': False},

'Giant Eagle': {
        'Height (m)': 1.5,
        'Weight (kg)': 52,
        'Color': 'Black and White',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': True},

'Ancient Vulture': {
        'Height (m)': 2.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 70,
        'Color': 'Brown',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Aggressive': False}
}

actions = ['Back Away', 'Cover our Heads', 'Take a Photograph']

def show_actions(birds):
    for name, attrs in birds.items():
        acs = []
        if attrs['Aggressive']:
            acs.append(actions[1])
        if attrs['Endangered']:
            acs.append(actions[0])
        if not acs:
            acs.append(actions[2])
        yield (name, *acs)

for bird, *acs in show_actions(rarebirds):
    print(f"{bird}: {', '.join(acs)}")
```

produces

```
Gold-crested Toucan: Cover our Heads, Back Away
Pearlescent Kingfisher: Take a Photograph
Four-metre Hummingbird: Back Away
Giant Eagle: Cover our Heads, Back Away
Ancient Vulture: Take a Photograph
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final_actions={}
for key, value in rarebirds.items():
    if final_actions.get(key)==None:
        final_actions[key]=[]
    if 'Aggressive' in value and value.get("Aggressive")==True:
        final_actions[key].append(actions[1])
    if 'Endangered' in value and value.get("Endangered")==True:
        final_actions[key].append(actions[0])
    if ('Aggressive' in value and value.get("Aggressive")==False) and ('Endangered' in value and value.get("Endangered")==False):
        final_actions[key].append(actions[2])
print(final_actions)
```

You will get answer as:

```
{
   "Four-metre Hummingbird":[
      "Back Away"
   ],
   "Giant Eagle":[
      "Cover our Heads",
      "Back Away"
   ],
   "Gold-crested Toucan":[
      "Cover our Heads",
      "Back Away"
   ],
   "Pearlescent Kingfisher":[
      "Take a Photograph"
   ],
   "Ancient Vulture":[
      "Take a Photograph"
   ]
}
```

Moreover,

```
   for value in value:
        if value == 'Aggressive' and True:
```

The above piece of code is wrong in your code.
Instead of this, you can try

```
for nested_value in value:
        if nested_value == 'Aggressive' and value.get(nested_value)==True:
```